# Why do form builders have a $form parameter?

Tags: 8, forms

In Drupal 8, the first parameter of `FormInterface::buildForm()` is `$form`.

When implementing a form builder, one has the option of either adding stuff to this existing array and returning it, or creating a new $form array, discarding what was passed into the function. In my experience, both of these options usually work fine.

What's the point? Is there ever a case when this parameter is needed?

I think to vaguely remember that this is somehow relevant when a form is rebuilt, so this would be the old form.. but I would not really know what to do with it.

Comment: `Is there ever a case when this parameter is needed?` How do you create or alter form fields? ;)

Comment: In [formInterface::buildForm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormInterface.php/function/FormInterface%3A%3AbuildForm/8.5.x) it says, "**array $form:** An associative array containing the structure of the form."

Comment: Yeah but this function is responsible for building the form array, usually from scratch. So the return value should be "the structure of the form". Why does it have to be passed in as a parameter?

Comment: Many form builder implementations do not really care about this parameter, they just start with an empty array `$form = []`, and then add elements.

Comment: Looking in `$form` on a new build, a rebuild and an ajax request, it's always empty, except a class in #attributes for the form id. So this is a very good question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The original question applied to Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 alike. Your edit makes it only apply to Drupal 8. Why?

Comment: We don't use two version tags.

Comment: So I would have to ask the same question twice?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Following the policy I created a separate question for D7. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292113/why-do-d7-form-builders-have-a-form-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Its an interesting question as there are now two ways of altering forms.

Using [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.4.x) ie [book_form_node_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_form_node_form_alter/8.4.x) with $form **by ref** and by *inheritance* **returning** $form as done in ie \Drupal\forum\Form\Overview::buildForm

```
class Overview extends OverviewTerms {
  ...
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    ...
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state, $vocabulary);
    ...
    return $form;
  }
  ...
}
```

where \Drupal\taxonomy\Form\OverviewTerms::buildForm gets called using **$form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state, $vocabulary);** thus in fact zapping $form.

Most code seems to **return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state, ...);** which we could call 'method' 3.

I guess hook_form_alter will disappear in the next version (10.x?) in favour of event listeners

Comment: I would not think of inheritance as a way of "altering" forms. For me, form_alter and form building are distinct concepts.

Comment: As for the `parent::buildForm($form, ..);`, here it depends what the parent implementation does. Sometimes the parent implementation zaps, sometimes it does not.

Comment: We can conclude form building can be done in several different ways which is confusing :-) ... regarding inheritance check what I did with `class TourBuilderListBuilder extends TourListBuilder` where I replace the TourListBuilder. It's altering by `tour_builder_entity_type_alter`

Comment: Do you mean this? http://cgit.drupalcode.org/tour_builder/tree/src/TourBuilderListBuilder.php

Comment: My previous comment was misleading. Sure you can "alter" the form of a parent form builder. But this does not explain the $form parameter being passed into the form builder.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure where we are going. Do you disagree with my answer? Or did I miss something? If so please edit my answer. And we could delete comments not to cluster things :-)

Comment: I just don't think it answers the question. Also, calling `$form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state, $vocabulary);` does not necessarily mean "zapping the form". If the parent implementation returns the `$form` array passed into it, nothing is zapped.