# Why do D7 form builders have a $form parameter?

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7, the first parameter of a form builder function is $form.

When implementing a form builder function, one has the option of either adding stuff to this existing array and returning it, or creating a new $form array, discarding what was passed into the function. In my experience, both of these options usually work fine.

What's the point? Is there ever a case when this parameter is needed?

I think to vaguely remember that this is somehow relevant when a form is rebuilt, so this would be the old form.. but I would not really know what to do with it.

*Note: The same question [already exists for Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244480/why-do-form-builders-have-a-form-parameter), but it seems to be a policy here that we need distinct questions for D7 and D8. I was going to answer it for D7, and I realize it would be off-topic in the D8 question.*

Answer (score 2):

At least for D7 there is one scenario where the passed-in $form parameter does make a difference.

With `hook_forms()`, it is possible to define a `'wrapper_callback'` for a form definition for a specific form id.

From the hook documentation https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/7.69/modules/system/system.api.php#L1821:

```php
/**
 [..]
 *   - wrapper_callback: (optional) Any callable to invoke before the form
 *     builder defined in 'callback' is invoked. This wrapper callback may
 *     prepopulate the $form array with form elements, which will then be
 *     already contained in the $form that is passed on to the form builder
 *     defined in 'callback'. For example, a wrapper callback could setup
 *     wizard-like form buttons that are the same for a variety of forms that
 *     belong to the wizard, which all share the same wrapper callback.
 */
```

So if a wrapper callback was defined, then the $form array passed as a parameter may already be prepopulated.

I found some contrib modules where this is being used (simply grep for 'wrapper_callback'):

- [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) does not set the wrapper callback in `hook_forms()`, instead it sets `$form_state['wrapper_callback']` directly.
- [entity](https://drupal.org/project/entity) uses hook_forms() to set a wrapper callback to a form definition, but also sets it in `$form_state['wrapper_callback']` directly.
- [media_bulk_upload](https://drupal.org/project/media_bulk_upload) does use `hook_forms()` to specify a wrapper callback.